# Getting undefined when mapping data from Pick

Tags: javascript, typescript, mongodb

Got the `IProduct` interface -

```
interface IProduct extends IDBCollection {
    readonly category: ProductCategory;
    readonly gender: ProductGender;
    readonly title: string;
    readonly description: string;
    readonly price: number;
    readonly imageFileName: string;
}
```

Got the products which i get from the DB -

```
const products: ReadonlyArray<Pick<IProduct, 'id' | 'category' | 'gender' | 'title' | 'description' | 'price' | 'imageFileName'>> = await UserDB.aggregate<
    Pick<IProduct, 'id' | 'category' | 'gender' | 'title' | 'description' | 'price' | 'imageFileName'>>([
      {
        $match: { _id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.userId) },
      },
      {
        $lookup: {
          from: 'products',
          localField: 'inBagProducts',
          foreignField: '_id',
          as: 'products',
        },
      },
      {
        $unwind: '$products',
      },
      {
        $project: { 
          products: 1
        },
      },
    ]);
```

Thats is the data I'm getting from `products[0]` (for example) -

```
{
  _id: 611e2febb863ce74ac448220,
  products: {
    _id: 610c8269da39093228dbe285,
    category: 4,
    gender: 2,
    title: 'refmkeipinv',
    description: 'odsfbndsofbndsfobnsonfgosingois',
    price: 989,
    imageFilename: '1628209769484-7927.png',
    createdAt: 2021-08-06T00:29:29.521Z,
    updatedAt: 2021-08-06T00:29:29.521Z,
    __v: 0
  }
}
```

When I'm tring to `console.log(products.map((product) => product.category));` I get undefined.

How can i `console.log` the data?

Comment: Judging by your example, would it not be `product.products.category`?

Comment: @futur I don't even get that option

Comment: Strange. If I understand your question correctly, `products[0]` is the object in your last snippet, correct? It has two properties: `_id` and `products`, of which the latter has a property `category`. So does `products[0].products.category` not work?

Comment: @futur the problem is the Pick<>, i got a type problem. not sure how to solve it

Comment: @futur https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68868494/how-to-access-nested-filed-with-pick-typescript