# How to access nested filed with Pick<> typescript

Tags: typescript, mongodb, mongoose

Got this code which getting the ptoducts -

```
const products: ReadonlyArray<Pick<IProduct, 'id' | 'gender' | 'title' | 'description' | 'price' | 'imageFileName'>> = await UserDB.aggregate<
    Pick<IProduct, 'id' | 'gender' | 'title' | 'description' | 'price' | 'imageFileName'>>([
    **Some mongoDB action so i deleted them**
    ]);
```

So now the `products` type is the `Pick<Iproduct, >`

When I want to access the product fields with `map` I can only use it in this way -

```
console.log(products.map((product) => product.products.category));
```

And the problem is I can't use - `product**.products**.category` because of the `Pick<Iproduct, >`

And that's the way i can use the `map` which gets undefined -

```
 console.log(products.map((product) => product.category));
```

What can i do about it?

Example data -

```
{
    _id: 611e2febb863ce74ac448220,
    products: {
      _id: 6116a9ecc3e98d500c5e523d,
      category: 5,
      gender: 1,
      title: 'sivdosi',
      description: 'oisbdvoi',
      price: 2394,
      imageFileName: 'http://localhost:3000/images/1628875244435-3564.png',
      createdAt: 2021-08-13T17:20:44.472Z,
      updatedAt: 2021-08-13T17:20:44.472Z,
      __v: 0
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

The [`map` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is for arrays, so I'll assume your `products` key in your example is an array and not an object.

First, I'd suggest you properly write type definitions for your products response if you haven't already

```
interface IProduct {
  _id: string,
  category: number,
  gender: number,
  title: string,
  description: string,
  price: number,
  imageFileName: string,
  createdAt: string,
  updatedAt: string,
  __v: number
}

interface IResponse {
  _id: string;
  products: IProduct[];
}
```

Then, to get `Pick` working on a single `product` object, you can index the `IResponse` interface by using [Indexed Access Types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html). You want the `products` property at an `index`because it's an array.

```
/*

Indexed Access Types

type Person = { age: number, name: string }[];
type Age = Person[number]["age"];

*/

type Products = ReadonlyArray<
  Pick<
    IResponse["products"][number],
    "_id" | "gender" | "title" | "description" | "price" | "imageFileName"
  >
>;
```

If you were to do something like `Pick<IResponse["products"], '_id'...>` you'd be trying to use `Pick` to extract properties from an array, which would result in an error.

And the only thing left is to map the products from the response to the desired object shape.

```
// Query your products

const { products }: IResponse = {
  _id: "611e2febb863ce74ac448220",
  products: [
    {
      _id: "6116a9ecc3e98d500c5e523d",
      category: 5,
      gender: 1,
      title: 'sivdosi',
      description: 'oisbdvoi',
      price: 2394,
      imageFileName: 'http://localhost:3000/images/1628875244435-3564.png',
      createdAt: "2021-08-13T17:20:44.472Z",
      updatedAt: "2021-08-13T17:20:44.472Z",
      __v: 0
    }
  ]
}

// Get the desired object

const pickedProducts: Products = products.map(({ _id, gender, title, description, price, imageFileName }) => ({
  _id,
  gender,
  title,
  description,
  price,
  imageFileName
}));
```

The final result looks something like the following

```
interface IProduct {
  _id: string,
  category: number,
  gender: number,
  title: string,
  description: string,
  price: number,
  imageFileName: string,
  createdAt: string,
  updatedAt: string,
  __v: number
}

interface IResponse {
  _id: string;
  products: IProduct[];
}

type Products = ReadonlyArray<
  Pick<
    IResponse["products"][number],
    "_id" | "gender" | "title" | "description" | "price" | "imageFileName"
  >
>;

// Query your products

const { products }: IResponse = {
  _id: "611e2febb863ce74ac448220",
  products: [
    {
      _id: "6116a9ecc3e98d500c5e523d",
      category: 5,
      gender: 1,
      title: 'sivdosi',
      description: 'oisbdvoi',
      price: 2394,
      imageFileName: 'http://localhost:3000/images/1628875244435-3564.png',
      createdAt: "2021-08-13T17:20:44.472Z",
      updatedAt: "2021-08-13T17:20:44.472Z",
      __v: 0
    }
  ]
}

// Get the desired object

const pickedProducts: Products = products.map(({ _id, gender, title, description, price, imageFileName }) => ({
  _id,
  gender,
  title,
  description,
  price,
  imageFileName
}));
```

- [TypeScript Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIAUoHsAmBXBMZAbwFgAoZZAfWBwC5kBnMKUAcwBoKqE5J2WKAE9GIPAFsARtG6Vk7CCBzQxkmVDlUwwMABsIjFmxBceyFUwRsADjqwgjrDluQ22SNdNnngEuIoAYsAGAHJwEobMzqau1hD8EDgAgmBOJmbyeDY4iSlp0Rmu1NQAbl4aFAC+FBSgkLCIKKgAShBMNg5MKGTytAyFHADc5u64BGBMjBjY+IQA2gC6I+Q15BRgwjYomOOETMgAvMhtcDgOesLJUFBwwgA85ujACADWj-JUre2dIN3zACIxnNJgDFvNxN4oItXFQAf0AcgAD7IAGKZTQREogE6fQQLGoyzWYB2YAOAlAjz45GovwBCDBMIRfHmAB8FFZKwoAHpucgAIp4aDCZDCLB4KBuWYTJi1cgILpEYhSvaTZBVaZtDpdFDHXpUfqMAEANgAjKaIAAmGAQKRSAAcxoAzEgAOwAFkQ7vd9stloADADXMCZYx5uYqPqqNHDaizabjXAAJwQBAIJ0QJP2nAAVn9-oQOYgOctTpwQYj0b4AiEomQOdh0fRKigjFNje0ugMjAA5ExgKVzv2ex2LO1iaSHL2sMAmFIcKUZyPK1R3C8oqWk+7R3SgiEIOFIr2ABZgMA2ei8vRYPh6Y9YFj0J35-3c3ftbkJy32+2ukve90nRzABaIDjXdAA6GxTGXT4qygBJIHyI0A0tU1gP9e1gNNJ0ABVTVdegA3ob0IPdV1LQALQrOCqGyXIkNSFD-TQjCsJw-DCOI0jyKomjoxjMpGH9Ss1ioRZqjlBU-iIGwXleJJdhBKZkCUmUjhVZSIP8GwAApdOVfpOAUJQW2M3EDGMolbHsEBjLXJBjPfRkD2ZdUAEojlZZADPMIzzGbHx5AsiBXGsklbODKlXGc-dDwgap3PcoYgA)